# Using optparse-applicative with multiple subcommands and global options

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

I am writing a commandline program that takes multiple subcommands, which take flags/arguments.

The program should also take some 'global-flags' that are applicable to all subcommands. For examples:

```
myProgram --configfile=~/.customrc UPLOADFILE --binary myfile.x
myProgram --configfile=~/.customrc SEARCH --regex "[a-z]+"
```

in this example, the subcommands are `UPLOADFILE` and `SEARCH`, and `configfile` is relevant to both subcommands, and `binary` and `regex` applicable to the specific subcommands.

I feel this must be possible with this library, but I am struggling to work out what to put where! I am relatively new to Haskell, trying to get my head around applicatives, and it making my brain hurt :)

There is an example of subcommands here in the [documentation for the
module](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative#commands), but I can't seem to work out how to get the global-flags to work.

If someone could point me towards a small working example, or insight into how I shoud structure code to do this, I would be very grateful, I am finding these higher order functions slightly magical!

Many thanks for your time. Best wishes,

Mike

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation you linked has this to say:

> Commands are useful to implement command line programs with multiple
>   functions, each with its own set of options, and **possibly some global**
>   **options that apply to all of them.**

Although it does not say precisely how those options should be applied. If you look at the types, however, you can gain some insight. The example indicates to use `subparser`, whose type is `Mod CommandFields a -> Parser a`. This probably doesn't say much (especially the left hand side) but crucially this function just produces a `Parser` - so you can combine it with other parsers as you normally would:

```
data Subcommand 
  = Upload { binary :: String } 
  | Search { regex  :: String } deriving Show 

data Options = Options 
  { configFile :: FilePath 
  , subcommand :: Subcommand 
  } deriving Show 

commandO = Options <$> configFileO <*> subcommandO 

configFileO = strOption
   ( long "configfile"
  <> help "Filepath of configuration file" 
   )

subcommandO :: Parser Subcommand
subcommandO = subparser ...
```

Defining subcommands themselves is fairly straightforward - I just copied the example from the docs and renamed some things in accordance with your specific example:

```
subcommandO = 
  subparser
    ( command "UPLOADFILE" (info uploadO
        ( progDesc "Upload a file" ))
   <> command "SEARCH" (info searchO
        ( progDesc "Search in a file" ))
   )

uploadO = Upload <$> 
  ( strOption
     ( long "binary"
    <> help "Binary file to upload" 
     )
  )

searchO = Upload <$> 
  ( strOption
     ( long "regex"
    <> help "Regular expression to search for" 
     )
  )

main = execParser opt >>= print where 
  opt = info (helper <*> commandO)
     ( fullDesc
    <> progDesc "Example for multiple subcommands"
    <> header "myProgram" )
```

Running this program gives the following:

```
>:main --configfile=~/.customrc UPLOADFILE --binary myfile.x
Options {configFile = "~/.customrc", subcommand = Upload {binary = "myfile.x"}}

>:main --configfile=~/.customrc SEARCH --regex "[a-z]+"
Options {configFile = "~/.customrc", subcommand = Upload {binary = "[a-z]+"}}

>:main --help
myProgram

Usage: <interactive> --configfile ARG COMMAND
  Example for multiple subcommands

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
  --configfile ARG         Filepath of configuration file

Available commands:
  UPLOADFILE               Upload a file
  SEARCH                   Search in a file
*** Exception: ExitSuccess
```

Comment: When you illustrated the sample "running the program" is it really that it always returns a Upload data structure, with binary --- or would it not that one subCommand would be Upload with binary, and the other be Search and regex.

Comment: @Dr.YSG That was my mistake, `searchO = Upload <$> ...` should be `searchO = Search <$> ...`